# Apresentação de gráfico de rmarkdown desproporcional

Tags: r, ggplot2

Olá, estou com o seguinte problema: quando imprimo o gráfico no Rmarkdown ele fica com os números um por cima dos outros, além da indicação do mês/ano nas coordenadas também ficarem com a visualização errada..

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Há algum código para aumentar o tamanho do gráfico para isso não acontecer? Ou alguma ideia para melhorar?

```
ggplot(data = planilha.grafico, aes(x = Ano, y = value, color = type)) + 
  geom_line(size=1.0) + scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels 
= "%b/%Y") + 
 labs(title = "Gráfico 8: Evolução do Reajuste de Inativos",
       subtitle = "Fonte: Base de Dados SIGRH", x = " ", y = "Quantidade") + 
  theme(axis.line.x = element_line(size = .5, colour = "black"),
        axis.line.y = element_line(size = .5, colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black", size = 8),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black", size = 8),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom", legend.direction = "horizontal",
        legend.title = element_blank()) + 
  geom_point(size=1.5) +scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 160000)) + 
  geom_text(data = planilha.grafico, aes(x=Ano, y=value, label = value, 
vjust = -1.1), size=3)
```

dput dos dados utilizados para criar o gráfico

```
## structure(list(Ano = structure(c(16801, 16832, 16861, 16892, 
## 16922, 16953, 16983, 17014, 17045, 17075, 17106, 17136, 17167, 
## 16801, 16832, 16861, 16892, 16922, 16953, 16983, 17014, 17045, 
## 17075, 17106, 17136, 17167), class = "Date"), type = c("Paridade", 
## "Paridade", "Paridade", "Paridade", "Paridade", "Paridade", "Paridade", 
## "Paridade", "Paridade", "Paridade", "Paridade", "Paridade", "Paridade", 
## "Média", "Média", "Média", "Média", "Média", "Média", "Média", 
## "Média", "Média", "Média", "Média", "Média", "Média"), value = c(149160, 
## 149300, 149599, 149787, 150039, 150319, 150507, 150584, 151025, 
## 151380, 151429, 151952, 151827, 4227, 4231, 4229, 4240, 4251, 
## 4258, 4377, 4404, 4427, 4471, 4502, 4554, 4581)), row.names = c(NA, 
## -26L), .Names = c("Ano", "type", "value"), class = c("tbl_df", 
## "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Seria possível editar a pergunta colocar o resultado do comando `dput(planilha.grafico)`? Assim teríamos o teu conjunto de dados para trabalhar e tentar resolver o teu problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você controla isso nos parâmetros do *chunk* do RMarkdown:

````
```{r fig.width = 7, fig.height = 7}
# código do seu gráfico
```
````

`7` é o padrão de altura e largura, vai mexendo até você achar que ficou bom.
[Aqui](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/rmarkdown-reference.pdf) tem uma lista dos parâmetros que você pode mexer nos chunks. Colei abaixo os específicos dos gráficos. Se não funcionar a largura e altura você pode tentar mexer neles também. As vezes você tem que mexer com `out.width` e `out.height` também.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado, vou começar aqui!

Answer (score 3):

Eu cheguei no seguinte gráfico:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para isto, ajustei os seguintes parâmetros:

- Dentro de `theme`, opção `axis.text.x`, coloquei o argumento `angle=90`, para rotacionar a legenda do eixo x
- Na função `geom_text`, coloquei `hjust=0, vjust = -1.5` (em `aes`), e `angle = 45`, para poder rotacionar os labels dos pontos
- Aumentei o limite do eixo y usando `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 170000))`. Se eu não fizesse isso, os labels dos pontos não caberiam na imagem final.

O código completo ficou assim:

```
ggplot(data = planilha.grafico, aes(x = Ano, y = value, color = type)) + 
  geom_line(size=1.0) + scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b/%Y") + 
  labs(title = "Gráfico 8: Evolução do Reajuste de Inativos",
       subtitle = "Fonte: Base de Dados SIGRH", x = " ", y = "Quantidade") + 
  theme(axis.line.x = element_line(size = .5, colour = "black"),
        axis.line.y = element_line(size = .5, colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, colour = "black", size = 8),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black", size = 8),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom", legend.direction = "horizontal",
        legend.title = element_blank()) + 
  geom_point(size=1.5) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 170000)) + 
  geom_text(data = planilha.grafico, aes(x=Ano, y=value, label = value, 
    hjust=0, vjust = -1.5), size=3, angle = 45)
```

Comment: A solução anterior já havia satisfeito o que eu precisava, mas o seu gráfico ficou muito bom também.  Inclusive o angle que eu não tinha usado ainda!